# How to use localStorage on server side in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, playwright

I'm trying to access Browser localStorage from the server side. I have tried it using node-localStorage, store and store2 node libraries but nothing worked. When I checked the browser localStorage it was empty.

This my test.js

```
import playwright from 'playwright-core';
import response from '../token.json' assert {type: "json"};
import { LocalStorage } from "node-localstorage";
global.localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');

(async () => {

    const browser = await playwright["chromium"].launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 2000
    });

    const context = await browser.newContext();

    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/trader-desktop/login");

    localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
    localStorage.setItem('tokenType', response.tokenType);
    localStorage.setItem('tokenExpirationTime', response.tokenExpirationTime);
    localStorage.setItem('userId', response.userId);
    localStorage.setItem('realms', JSON.stringify(response.realms));
    localStorage.setItem('phone', response.phone);

    await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/trader-desktop/account-selection")

    await page.pause();
    
    await browser.close();

})();
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "type" : "module",
    
    "devDependencies": {
        "playwright": "1.21.1"
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "node-fetch": "^3.2.4",
        "node-localstorage": "^2.2.1",
        "store2": "^2.13.2",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can work this thing out? I can't use window.localStorage because window is not defined in node.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are setting _a_ localStorage, not browser.localStorage

Comment: You can't access the client's localStorage directly from the server.

Comment: plus those node packages that you are using are simply there to make your app isomorphic, e.g. that you can share more code between node and the browser, they basically implement the browser's localStorage API.

Comment: @AyushGupta I tried accessing browser.localStorage it didn't work

Comment: @Barmar So are you saying that it's impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked like a charm. Thanks to all your contributions.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const localStorage = fs.readFileSync('../localStorage.json', 'utf8')

    const deserializedStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage)
    await page.evaluate(deserializedStorage => {
        for (const key in deserializedStorage) {
            if (key === "realms") {
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(deserializedStorage[key]));
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem(key, deserializedStorage[key]);
            }
        }
    }, deserializedStorage);
```

[Source](https://dev.to/checkly/setting-state-using-cookies-1bk)

Comment: This is a file on the server, not the browser.

Comment: But I'm using it under page.evaluate(), it enables us to interact with the browser.